# Retrieve and compare the style attribute of an element periodically using using cypress

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, ui-testing

I have a time indicator that travels over a timescale, the indicator's style attribute value keeps on changing for every x milliseconds and I need to get, store and compare that the previously captured value is greater than the latest value.

**Initial value:**
[image]

**Latest value:**
[image]

The logic is, from one point (left 10), every second it moves to the left (left -0, -1, -2, -3 ...)

I tried few ways and one of them is to capture in the same 'cy.then', but in that case, the element will not have the recent value. So far, I tried this. it fetches the value and with some help of regex, I got a 'comparable' value but how I can store/compare those values? Additionally, what is the best way if we need to compare more than 2 values?

```
const BTN_CONTROL_TIMEINDICATOR = '#currentTimeIndicator'
  static verifyTimeLapse() {
        //wip
        var initialVal, nextVal
        initialVal = this.getAnyValueOfAnElement(BTN_CONTROL_TIMEINDICATOR)
        cy.wait(500)
        nextVal = this.getAnyValueOfAnElement(BTN_CONTROL_TIMEINDICATOR)
        cy.log(initialVal > nextVal) 
    }

  static getAnyValueOfAnElement(element) {
        //wip
        cy.get(element)
           .then(($ele) => {
               const val=$ele.attr('style').replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '')
               cy.log(val)
               // return does not work 
            })
    }
```

**cy.log:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page objects don't work very well with the Cypress command queue, here's what you might do with custom commands.

```js
/* Get the numeric value of CSS left in px */
Cypress.Commands.add('getTimescaleValue', () => {
  cy.get('#currentTimeIndicator')
    .then($el => +$el[0].style.left.replace('px',''))
})

/* Get a sequence of time scale values */
Cypress.Commands.add('getTimescaleValues', ({numValues, waitBetween}) => {
  const values = [];
  Cypress._.times(numValues, () => {          // repeat inner commands n times
    cy.getTimescaleValue()
      .then(value => values.push(value))      // save value
      .wait(waitBetween)
  })
  return cy.wrap(values);
})

/* Assert a sequence of values are in descending order */
Cypress.Commands.add('valuesAreDescending', { prevSubject: true }, (values) => {
  values.reduce((prev, current) => {
    if (prev) {                       // skip first (no prev to compare)
      expect(prev).to.be.gt(current)  // assert pairs of values 
    }
    return current
  });
})


it('check the timeline', () => {
  cy.getTimescaleValues({ numValues: 10, waitBetween: 100 })
    .valuesAreDescending()
})
```

Log

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | assert | expected 63 to be above 58 |
|  | assert | expected 58 to be above 48 |
|  | assert | expected 48 to be above 43 |
|  | assert | expected 43 to be above 33 |
|  | assert | expected 33 to be above 23 |
|  | assert | expected 23 to be above 18 |
|  | assert | expected 18 to be above 13 |
|  | assert | expected 13 to be above 3 |
|  | assert | expected 3 to be above -2 |

Tested with

```html
<div id="currentTimeIndicator" style="left:63px">Target</div>
<script>
  const timer = setInterval(() => {
    const div = document.querySelector('#currentTimeIndicator')
    const left = +div.style.left.replace('px', '');
    if (left < 0) {
      clearInterval(timer)
      return
    }
    const next = (left - 5) + 'px';
    div.style.left = next;
  }, 100)
</script>
```

If your app uses `setInterval()` for timing, you should be able to use `cy.clock()` and `cy.tick()` instead of `.wait(waitBetween)` to get more precise sampling and faster test execution.

Comment: It worked like a charm and thanks for explaining it with comments.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where the initial value comes from. But before it changes, maybe on page load, maybe as first job on click, etc you can do something like this:

```js
let item = document.querySelector("#currentTimeIndicator");
item.dataset.left = parseFloat(item.style.left);

console.log(item);
```

```html
<div id="currentTimeIndicator" style="left:-20px"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, It reads _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataset' of null
    at <anonymous>:2:6_

Comment: So when you call that code, there is no item to select. It should be a timing issue.